# Appending numbers to emptylist

Tags: python

im trying to return the divisors of 2 numbers that i appended to an empty list. why is nothing being printed? im expecting for 1,2,3 to be returned to mw but i get returned "[]" and "none"

```
def fun (t,g) :
    list1 = []
    i = 1
    r = 1
    while i < t :
        if i % t == 0 :
            list1.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    while r < g :
        if r % g == 0 :
            list1.append(r)
        r = r + 1
    print list1

x = 4
y = 6

t = fun(x,y)
print t
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?

Comment: i fixed it and added a return statement but i dont get the list printed back?

Comment: Try gnibbler's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`i % t` is never `0` since you are exiting the while loop when `i == t`. Perhaps you meant `t % i`?

Likewise for `r` and `g`.

Your function doesn't have a `return` so it will implicitly return `None`

You should add `return list1` to the end of it.

```
def fun (t,g) :
    list1 = []
    i = 1
    r = 1
    while i < t :
        if t % i == 0 :
            list1.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    while r < g :
        if g % r == 0 :
            list1.append(r)
        r = r + 1
    print list1
    return list1

x = 4
y = 6

t = fun(x,y)
print t
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

So you still need to work out the duplicates

Comment: 4 % 1 is 0.. it's the indentation, not the logic

Comment: @Leifingson, you have the `i` and `t` values transposed. For some reason it's common for new users to get the indentation of the first line wrong when posting code here.

Comment: @Leifingson it is the logic. If it's the indentation the program should throw indentation error

Comment: im sorry, it was the logic, didn't even see that. 2nd time i mix them, thanks

Comment: I see now. Yeah, 1 % 4... it's the logic

Comment: another question, anytime i have a print statement refering to a function, does the function have to return a value?

Comment: @ZachSantiago, yes a function always returns something. If you don't `return` anything, there is an implicit `return None`. It's ok to ignore the return value though